# Swift how to preserve navigation bar button items after push

Tags: ios, swift, view, controller, push

In my root view controller I set an array of bar button items with images and assign them to the right bar button.

When I push the next view controller my navigation bar resets and only displays a back button.

Any way to preserve the navigation bar as it was set on the root view controller so it will display on all pages?

Comment: In `prepareForSegue` set the destination view controller's right navigation items.

Answer (score 0):

As user1046037 has said you can set the item buttons while you are preparing the segue.

Example:

```
let helpViewController = HelpViewController(nibName: "HelpViewController", bundle: nil)
let someLeftButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.refresh, target: self, action: "someAction")
helpViewController.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = someLeftButton
helpViewController.navigationItem.leftItemsSupplementBackButton = true
navigationController?.pushViewController(helpViewController, animated: true)
```

This one is to preserve the left button item and the back one.

```
helpViewController.navigationItem.leftItemsSupplementBackButton = true
```

If you are going to use the same button in several Viewcontrollers you can create a BaseViewController setting up the button and his behaviors.

```
class AHBaseViewController: UIViewController {

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    configureNavigationBar()
    // Configure Common status bar if you want too.
  }

  func configureNavigationBar() {
    let someLeftButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.refresh, target: self, action: "someAction")
    navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = someLeftButton
    navigationItem.leftItemsSupplementBackButton = true
  }
}
```

Then just inherit it, in the viewControllers that you want to show the button(s).

```
class HelpViewController: AHBaseViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

When you segue between view controllers using Push, you're going to get the default "horizontal slide" navigation animation which. Try "present Modally" or "present as popover".